# build predictive model using R

Tags: r, model, linear-regression, predictive

I wanted to build predictive model using R . I used R studio as IDE.
I used heart disease regarding dataset and created data-model. My predictive value is categorical variable.

But when I add data-frame values to model I got below error:

```
Error in quantile.default(resid) : factors are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(r, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors
```

For this model I wanted to use multiple independent variables and predicted value is factor variable and will return 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. I found a solution.
Issue is I have used my output variable as a factor. Now I use as a number and error fixed.